# Path helper strange output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rake routes related output:

```
 colorschemes GET    /colorschemes(.:format)                 colorschemes#index
                       POST   /colorschemes(.:format)                 colorschemes#create
       new_colorscheme GET    /colorschemes/new(.:format)             colorschemes#new
      edit_colorscheme GET    /colorschemes/:id/edit(.:format)        colorschemes#edit
           colorscheme GET    /colorschemes/:id(.:format)             colorschemes#show
                       PUT    /colorschemes/:id(.:format)             colorschemes#update
                       DELETE /colorschemes/:id(.:format)             colorschemes#destroy
          choose_color GET    /choose_color(.:format)                 colorschemes#choose_color
```

When I use path helper:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', colorschemes_path(@colorscheme), :method=>:delete, :remote=>true %>
```

The output is: `Started DELETE "/colorschemes.4"`

instead of "`/colorschemes/4`"

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `colorscheme_path(@colorscheme)` - singular, not plural!